# SharePoint 2013 - Add List View Web Part to Subsite

Tags: list, web-part, sub-site

I am looking to add a list webpart to a Subsite. The list is on the parent site. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The List View Web Part can be saved from the parent site as either a file or directly to the Web Part gallery. After that the web part can be added to the sub site.

See http://sharepointontop.blogspot.com/2012/06/show-listview-webpart-from-parent-site.html for detailed instructions.

Comment: Thank you. This was essentially the solution I found all over the internet but little did I know that there were a few things standing in my way. Apparently if you change the layout to Olso you cannot use this method to save web parts. Additionally, Server Rendering needs to be flipped on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use content query webpart ,where you can display list from the parent-site and add the columns as per your requirement.

[image]

Comment: Sorry this doesn't display the list in the same fashion that it displays on the main page. This is not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting the "List does not exist..." error when you try to save a SharePoint List as a web part in SharePoint Designer?

There is an easy but completely undocumented way to fix this.  You must create a new custom view that uses a "Style" of "Basic Table".  Then when you go into SharePoint Designer, click on that new custom view (I name all of mine SPDesigner just for simplicity / consistency), and then click inside the page and then click "LIST VIEW TOOLS >> WEB PART >> To Site Gallery".  After you do this a pop-up window will come up asking if you want to maintain the original list data.  If this pop-up does not appear, your web part will not work right.

Thanks!